# Admob ad won't display in an dialog themed activity

Tags: java, android, dialog, themes, admob

What i have is a simple activity with some content inside of it. Right below that I have an admob ad. And it works great.

However, when i add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to the activity in the manifest the activity still loads, the content loads, but then the ad will NOT load.

If i simply delete `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` and view the activity as a regular activity it works fine again. But, I need this to work in a dialog :/ So, any ideas what I could do? Anyone have the same issue?

Maybe an admob bug? I just don't see why this isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get the Ad to display in a dialog.  I had to display the dialog in landscape layout because there is not enough room for the Ad in portrait mode (as the ad takes up the full width of the screen).  However, clicking on the ad does nothing (the ad does not redirect to the advertisers site).